# Regex get group n from group results

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a result from a database query that is:

```
IEnumerable<ResultRecord> results_from_db_call = Db.GoGetItNow();
```

Now lets assume the returned class looks like:

```
public class ResultsRecord
{
    public string DataBlob { get; set; }

    public int FirstID { get; set; }
    public int SecondNum { get; set; }
    public DateTime ThirdDate { get; set; }
    public string FourthTime { get; set; }
    public string FifthTime { get; set; }

}
```

Now, the result records returned only have the DataBlob member set

It very well might look like:

```
<IK/12322>1354654  16/MAY/2014 18:01:01 - 20:01:01
```

So, I need to fill the other members, and would like to do so with an 'Each' delegate:

```
results.Each(f => f.FirstID = int.Parse(Regex.Match(f.DataBlob, @"\d+").Value));
results.Each(f => f.SecondNum = int.Parse(Regex.Match(f.DataBlob, @"\d+").Value));
results.Each(f => f.ThirdDate = DateTime.Parse(Regex.Match(f.DataBlob, @"\d+").Value));
results.Each(f => f.FourthTime = Regex.Match(f.DataBlob, @"\d+").Value));
results.Each(f => f.FifthTime = Regex.Match(f.DataBlob, @"\d+").Value));
```

Well, as you can imagine, that regex expression only worked on the first integer..

But wait! I have a working Regex to find all the groups I need:

```
(\d+)\>(\d+)  (\d+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/\d+) (\d+\:\d+\:\d+) - (\d+\:\d+\:\d+)
```

This successfully groups all items that I need.

But, and here's the question, how do I get the second regex group item for SecondNum, the third regex group item for ThirdDate, the fourth regex group item for FourthTime, and the fifth regex group item for FifthTime?

When I try

```
 (\d+)\>(\d+)  (\d+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/\d+) (\d+\:\d+\:\d+) - (\d+\:\d+\:\d+){0}
```

I don't get the first (zeroth) item.

How can I call the regex to get the first, etc item from the groupings?

```
results.Each(f => f.SecondNum = int.Parse(Regex.Match(f.DataBlob, @"????").Value));
```

Answer (score -1):

You should parse the whole string first so that you will be able to capture different groups:

```
string pattern = @"(\d+)\>(\d+)  (\d+\/[a-zA-Z]+\/\d+) (\d+\:\d+\:\d+) - (\d+\:\d+\:\d+)";
Match m = Regex.Match(f.DataBlob, pattern);
// You can then refer to the matched group this way:
// m.Groups[1] = 12322
// m.Groups[2] = 1354654
// ...etc
Group g = m.Groups[2];
// Then parse into integer
```

Do note that capture group starts from **1**, instead of 0. You can also take a look at the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2).

Comment: Can't use that in a List<Type> Obj.Each. That was stated in the question.

Comment: Actually, your answer made me think of how efficient I wasn't being... I now do one regex in a loop of all items... but I could call: results.Each(f => f.SecondNum = int.Parse(Regex.Match(f.DataBlob, pattern).Groups[2].Value));

Comment: I'm not familiar with the language you are using. I was just explaining in terms of general regex usage because you were not using capture groups at all though you have captured them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about groups? Each (blaw blaw) is a group, so I am capturing groups. What do you mean? The language I'm using is C#.

Comment: Yes, on top of that, `blaw blaw` is being saved in regex as group 1 if it's the first one. See [this example](http://regex101.com/r/pH9lZ6/1). If you see the middle of the right pane "Match Information", your data is being captured from group 1 to 5. These are called capture groups in regex and to use them, you simply use `\1` to refer to group 1, etc. The syntax is different among languages. For php, it's `\1`. `$1` for javascript. And what i posted above is for C#. You can read [perl regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-groups) for some additional info.

Comment: I understood that the groups were being saved, and that the index is 1 based. However, my point was, I wanted to reference the nth item via the regex expression itself, as a qualifier of the match, and not to work on the resulting groups of captured items after the regex expression completes. I wanted a one line rexgex expression to capture the nth element, depending on the composition of the regex expression. Do you understand the requirements now?